# Min / Max function of 1D array in C / C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, array, reinventing-the-wheel

Due to software constraints, I cannot use the standard libraries, `<math.h>`, `<algorithm>`, templates, `inline`, or Boost. I am also using standard C (ISO C99) such that `array` is not a reserved keyword like it is in Visual Studio.

Is this the "best" possible implementation of a min function? This needs to be robust and fast. Is there a more efficient C++ implementation?

```
double min(double* array, int size){
    // returns the minimum value of array
    static double val = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i){
        val = val <= array[i] ? val : array[i];
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the software constraints you have to work within? I can understand not using boost but not allowing math.h, algorithms, and templates either? That's ruling out some very useful tools offered by the language as well as reinventing the proverbial wheel as shown by your sample.

Comment: @VictorT.,the short answer is due to certification issues and extreme V&V. Trust me, I wish I didn't have these constraints, but really appreciate the resources SE provides

Comment: Is there a guarantee that size > 0? Otherwise you just stepped past the end of your array.

Comment: @Tux: If this *must* be optimized for efficiency then the onus will be on the caller to provide only valid data, not the other way around.

Comment: @Ed S.: Quote: `This needs to be robust`

Comment: @Tux-D: Yeah, I saw that two.  I don't think that the OP meant it that way though, but I'm really guessing.  Performance critical functions do not perform a ton of input validation (or any at all) by design.  For example, look at the C standard library.

Comment: Lets assuming the user knows what the input typedefs are and not worry about type casting, etc.

Comment: Use C++ inline templates, or you can use uber-macros to emulate templates in C http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=44426, http://drdobbs.com/184402989, or the most famous, and were my best searches so far (using google, of cause): BYTE WORM blog post at  http://byteworm.com/2010/10/12/container/

Comment: @ArturMustafin, cannot use templates

Comment: @Artur: The first sentence states that the OP can't use templates...

Comment: @EdS.: I've added code sample in my post to code review. This is the SSE version of the peaks algorithm, compiles for both GCC and VC++. Look may be you will find it helpful.

Comment: In my opinion, SSE implementation is better than "classic" CPU inctructions cycle for the big arrays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not quite the best.  There's some things IMHO that is hindering its performance and usefulness.

There's no point in declaring `val` as a static variable.  In fact, you've killed any chance of it being usable in multi-threaded programs.

The body of the loop is performing an assignment in every single iteration when it doesn't need to.  If you want it to be its best, you should only be doing so when it is required.

Your overall structure is fine, assuming we can expect well-formed inputs where array is nonempty and size is positive, I'd just change it so it's more like this:

```
double min(const double *arr, size_t length) {
    // returns the minimum value of array
    size_t i;
    double minimum = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
        if (minimum > arr[i]) {
            minimum = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure any half-decent optimising compiler will remove the redundant assignment in the original code's ternary operator.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i++` in stead of `++i`? Since you're pre-incrementing and starting at `1`, in the first iteration `i` would already be `2` at the `if` statement.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: It doesn't really matter which one is used, in the context of a `for` loop, they are exactly the same, increment `i`.  The incrementing expression is evaluated between the execution of the body and the condition check and has no other effect on the two.

Comment: Wow, how amateurish of me. I've been programming for years now, and could have sworn I was right. But I just tested this myself, and you are absolutely right. Silly me. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a performance reason for moving the `int i` declaration out of the loop?

Comment: @S.L.Barth: It's the C side in me moving the declaration to the beginning of the scope.  I tend to think in (old) C more than I do C++ and the relaxed restrictions.  No reason at all really.

Comment: Another improvement would be change the typedef of size,i from `int` to `size_t`

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Yes definitely.  We could even go for `const` correctness here and make `array` a `const char *`.

Comment: @JeffMercado, why would val be a `const char *`? Is it because array is a `double *`? A technical response would be appreciated

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Oops, I meant `const double *`.

Comment: @JeffMercado, `val` can change its value, hence isn't it `mutable`? Why would we want to declare it as a `const`? Is it because `const double*` means that the pointer is const but not the double[] it is pointing to?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: By declaring the type of the array `const double *`, we're stating that the contents of the array could not be changed.  i.e., The array is immutable.  We can still read the contents and store it on a non-const `double` as long as we don't modify the contents of the array.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I was little confused on what you wear declaring as `const double` but you've updated the answer to properly reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: I've added code sample in my post to code review. This is the SSE version of the peaks algorithm, compiles for both GCC and VC++. Look may be you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use SSE2/SSE3 minps / pminsd or relevant instruction set for your processor/architectoure since it is supported directly in GCC / MASM / TASM (In case MASM or TASM is not supported such SSE2/SSE3 instruction set there are also the .inc files to create macros simulating instruction sets on the web for MASM), create .OBJ file by your favorite linker then link it as usual and use in you favorite IDE. You will get from 4x to 16x performance boost compared to the traditional "classic" algorithm. It depend on data size (old compilers treats double not in IEEE format, bout like float in several configurations, on 16x systems, particularly, double means 32 bit data structure, not 64 bit data structure, in modern languages it is correlated to "double" and "long double" data structures, respectively)

The idea is simple: if you have k elements, [k=4n+p, 4>p=>0], complete it with n-p elements or just load last 4 doubles resetting to 0 last p elements, so you can fast evaluate n candidates. evaluate candidates n times comparing to the accumulator, you will get a minimum.

If your processor supports SSE5 or is a brand new, most likely you also will be using one of the HD instructions, which really handy, because it can find maximum (not minimum yet) in array of double values.

Sample of using SSE to calculate peak values of a float array:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

double min(double* array, int size) { 
    // returns the minimum value of array 
    int i; 
    double val = array[0]; 
    for (i = 1; i < size; ++i) { 
        if (val > array[i]) { 
            val = array[i]; 
        } 
    } 
    return val; 
} 

#define ARRAY_SIZE 16

float m_fArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

void x86_sse_find_peaks(float *buf, unsigned nframes, float *min, float *max)
{
    __m128 current_max, current_min, work;

    // Load max and min values into all four slots of the XMM registers
    current_min = _mm_set1_ps(*min);
    current_max = _mm_set1_ps(*max);

    // Work input until "buf" reaches 16 byte alignment
    while ( ((unsigned long)buf) % 16 != 0 && nframes > 0) {

        // Load the next float into the work buffer
        work = _mm_set1_ps(*buf);

        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);

        buf++;
        nframes--;
    }

    // use 64 byte prefetch for quadruple quads
    while (nframes >= 16) {
        //__builtin_prefetch(buf+64,0,0); // for GCC 4.3.2+

        work = _mm_load_ps(buf);
        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);
        buf+=4;
        work = _mm_load_ps(buf);
        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);
        buf+=4;
        work = _mm_load_ps(buf);
        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);
        buf+=4;
        work = _mm_load_ps(buf);
        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);
        buf+=4;
        nframes-=16;
    }

    // work through aligned buffers
    while (nframes >= 4) {

        work = _mm_load_ps(buf);

        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);

        buf+=4;
        nframes-=4;
    }

    // work through the rest < 4 samples
    while ( nframes > 0) {

        // Load the next float into the work buffer
        work = _mm_set1_ps(*buf);

        current_min = _mm_min_ps(current_min, work);
        current_max = _mm_max_ps(current_max, work);

        buf++;
        nframes--;
    }

    // Find min & max value in current_max through shuffle tricks

    work = current_min;
    work = _mm_shuffle_ps(work, work, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
    work = _mm_min_ps (work, current_min);
    current_min = work;
    work = _mm_shuffle_ps(work, work, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
    work = _mm_min_ps (work, current_min);

    _mm_store_ss(min, work);

    work = current_max;
    work = _mm_shuffle_ps(work, work, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
    work = _mm_max_ps (work, current_max);
    current_max = work;
    work = _mm_shuffle_ps(work, work, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
    work = _mm_max_ps (work, current_max);

    _mm_store_ss(max, work);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float   min = FLT_MAX;
    float   max = FLT_MIN;

    m_fArray[0] = 0;
    m_fArray[1] = 1;
    m_fArray[2] = 2;
    m_fArray[3] = 3;
    m_fArray[4] = 4;
    m_fArray[5] = 3;
    m_fArray[6] = 2;
    m_fArray[7] = 1;
    m_fArray[8] = -1;
    m_fArray[9] = -2;
    m_fArray[10] = -3;
    m_fArray[11] = -4;
    m_fArray[12] = -5;
    m_fArray[13] = -6;
    m_fArray[14] = -7;
    m_fArray[15] = -8;

    x86_sse_find_peaks(m_fArray, ARRAY_SIZE, &min, &max);

    printf("value = %.2f, max = %.2f\n", min, max); // output is: value = -8.00, max = 4.00
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great peaks implementation but I am working with `double` and don't want to downcast. If I recall, SSE was originally designed for floats. I've read that SSE can now handle double precision values, but not sure how to change your above code to handle doubles.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: I will definitely make it a try, would you mind that i will use Visual Studio 11 to compile C++ code, I'm also having a Borland C++, TASM in Windows XP virtual machine under Windows 7?

Comment: sure I am happy with the code current state. Anything beyond this is really for research curiosity and the good for all, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Recommended form for robustness:**

Ok, you want robust and fast. If this was needed in production code, I would probably write it like this:

```
double min(double array[], int size)
{
    assert(array != NULL);
    assert(size >= 0);

    if ((array == NULL) || (size <= 0))
       return NAN;

    double val = -DBL_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (val < array[i])
            val = array[i];
    return val;
}
```

*Looping:* I noticed you optimized your loop to begin with `val = array[0]` initially and `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`. This may have saved machine cycles 20 years ago, but these days memory accesses are the biggest bottleneck, and you're stuck with the same number of memory accesses into `array[]` no matter how you write the loop, so I would try to be as non-clever as possible here and just stick to a more traditional loop.

*Argument checking:* Is it valid to call this function with `size` of 0? If so, then you also have a bug if you start off with `val = array[0]` when `size` is 0, because you might be reading invalid memory depending on where `array` is pointing.  At the very least, it's logically incorrect to examine `array[0]` when `size` is 0.

**Alternative formulation (not recommended):**

Just for fun, if you have a sufficiently large stack and lots of machine cycles to burn, you could write it like this:

```
double min(double a[], int n)
{
    if ((a == NULL) || (n <= 0))
    {
        return NAN;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return array[0];
    }
    else
    {
        double x = a[0], y = min(&a[1], n-1);
        return x < y? x : y;
    }
}
```

Or, a recursive binary search using only O(log₂ n) stack space:

```
inline double min2(double x, double y)
{
    return x < y? x : y;
}

double min(double a[], int n)
{
    return (a == NULL) || (n <= 0)? NAN
         : (n == 1)? a[0]
         : min2(min(a, n/2), min(a+n/2, n-n/2));
}
```

Or, in avoidance of error-checking and in adherence to the principle of maximum terseness:

```
inline double min2(double x, double y) { return x<y? x:y; }
double min(double a[], int n) { return n==1? a[0] : min2(min(a,n/2),min(a+n/2,n-n/2)); }
```

;-)